# Hold ion-header when open new page in ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want create app same image 
[image]

With fist page I add button with event click

```js
 openHomePage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }
```

And in home page I add header and button with html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar persistent="true">
    <ion-label>Photogenic Map</ion-label>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only color="royal" (click)="MyPage()">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="MyPage()">Open Mypage</button>
</ion-content>
```

In mypage.js I added

```js
 MyPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(MyPage);
  }
```

But when open MyPage it not hold header bar from HomePage.
How I can custom html , js in HomePage and MyPage to when click button in header and content can open mypage an hold header?
Please share me your solution or idea.
Thank you so much!
Here is my demo

[my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-s7lyuk?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

[my demo](https://ionic-s7lyuk.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: Can you simulate what you have done so far here https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @Sampath I added my code in your link. Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot transfer header from one page to another.If you need to use that on another page then you need to use same code or you can create a `component` for that.

There is no property as `persistent` on `ion-toolbar`.But there is a `persistent` property on the [**Menu bar**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/).

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wg66vy?file=pages/mypage/mypage.html)

*mypage.html*

```
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-label>Photogenic Map</ion-label>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only color="royal" (click)="MyPage()">
                <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
 <h5>My Page</h5>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you do it if change mypage to modal or component? because if add header for each page, when open and close new page it will show animation and I can see bug in here. In android I can do it  with replace fragment but I do not know how to do the same thing in ionic

Comment: You cannot.`Modal` is also a `page`. But it works as a `popup`. But all others are same as `Page`. The `navigations` and `transitions` are different on the `modal`. The `component` is a reusable Angular building block. You cannot use it as an ionic page. But you can put your header part inside the component and after that, you can reuse it on any Ionic Page.

Comment: If you have a bug then you need to find out a solution for that.